# How do I expand my pands dataframe through a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a table like this in my pandas dataframe

| # | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | f | 1 |
| 1 | g | 2 |

But idk what code to write to transform it to

| # | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | f | 1a |
| 1 | f | 1b |
| 2 | g | 2a |
| 3 | g | 2b |

Comment: What is the logic? Why do you have two "2b"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want a cross product:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'#': [0, 1], 'A': list('fg'), 'B': [1, 2]})

l = ['a', 'b']

out = (
 df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(l))]
   .assign(**{'B': lambda d: d['B'].astype(str)+np.tile(l, len(df)),
              '#': lambda d: range(len(d))})
 )
```

Or with a cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = (
 df.merge(pd.Series(l, name='tmp'), how='cross')
   .assign(**{'B': lambda d: d['B'].astype(str)+d.pop('tmp'),
              '#': lambda d: range(len(d))})
)
```

Output:

```
   #  A   B
0  0  f  1a
0  1  f  1b
1  2  g  2a
1  3  g  2b
```

Comment: ah thnx this works. I'd upvote it but since I only ask beginner questions I probably have to make a new acc soon.

Comment: @vandam please don't make multiple accounts. Be patient, once you have sufficient reputation you you'll be able to ask questions more frequently!